# How can I fire cmd command "arp -a" in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to fire arp -a command in SQL in order to obtain the arp cache table.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can fire a shell command if thats what you mean. Permissions may cause issues

```
xp_cmdshell { 'command_string' } [ , no_output ]
```